# AES encryption between Android and Arduino

Tags: android, arduino, aes

Hi i'm working on a communication between android and arduino through a bluetooth module. And i have to introduce some security. I'm trying to put AES encryption but i have problems with that.
In my arduino code i can encrypt/decrypt using de AESlib of DavyLandman https://github.com/DavyLandman/AESLib and the sample code that he prepared

```
enter code here
```

uint8_t key[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p'};
        char data[] = "0123456789012345"; //16 chars == 16 bytes
        aes128_enc_single(key, data);
        Serial.print("encrypted:");
         Serial.println(data);
        aes128_dec_single(key, data);
        Serial.print("decrypted:");
         Serial.println(data);

and in android i also can encrypt/decrypt using an example founded on stackoverflow with a class AESHelper:

```
enter code here



    package com.example.bluetooth2;

import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESHelper {
    public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext)
            throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
        return toHex(result);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted)
            throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
        return new String(result);
    }

    private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG","Crypto");
        sr.setSeed(seed);
        kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
        return raw;
    }

    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
        return encrypted;
    }

    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted)
            throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }

    public static String toHex(String txt) {
        return toHex(txt.getBytes());
    }

    public static String fromHex(String hex) {
        return new String(toByte(hex));
    }

    public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
        int len = hexString.length() / 2;
        byte[] result = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2),
                    16).byteValue();
        return result;
    }

    public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
        if (buf == null)
            return "";
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2 * buf.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            appendHex(result, buf[i]);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
        sb.append(HEX.charAt((b >> 4) & 0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b & 0x0f));
    }

}


AND WITH THE MAIN ACTIVITY CODE:

    enter code here

     public static String seedValue = "abcdefghijklmnop";
    public static String MESSAGE = "Benfica";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            String encryptedData = AESHelper.encrypt(seedValue, MESSAGE);
            Log.v("EncryptDecrypt", "Encoded String " + encryptedData);
            String decryptedData = AESHelper.decrypt(seedValue, encryptedData);
            Log.v("Decrypt", "Decoded String " + decryptedData);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    }
```

But the problem is that i can't decrypt on arduino encrypted data from android and vice versa.

Anyone can help me?

I'm inexperient with this problem.

Mr Davy Landman from AESlib tell me to match the mode CBC. He tells that him code uses CBC mode, and in android i also tried to put this with the next two lines

AES/CBC/NoPadding
or
 AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

Please if anyone know how to correct, please save my life :)

Best regards

Comment: Start off by not basing anything on code of persons that think `getRawKey` is a good idea. An undefined random number generator should not be used as a key derivation function (unless you require different values of your key for encryption and decryption, but I don't think so).

Comment: Voting to close as there is no Arduino code in the questino, and SO is not a code translation service. Besides that, nobody should use random code from the internet, let alone if it generates keys that may not be reproduced ever again.